# Jquery autocomplete doesnt show Alabama, Alaska Arizona

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to show autocomplete so when you select state it should show the autocomplete cities for the selected state, somehow the 3 states are not displayed in the District textbox, not sure what is the error

```js
var USStates = [{
    "name": "Alabama",
    "cities": ["Birmingham", "Huntsville", "Mobile", "Montgomery"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Alaska",
    "cities": ["Anchorage", "Fairbanks", "Juneau", "Sitka"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Arizona",
    "cities": ["Chandler", "Gilbert", "Glendale", "Mesa", "Phoenix", "Scottsdale", "Tempe", "Tucson"]
  },
  "Arkansas",
  "California",
  "Colorado",
  "Delaware",
  "Florida",
  "Georgia",
  "Hawaii",
  "Idaho",
  "Illinois",
  "Indiana",
  "Kansas",
  "Kentucky",
  "Louisiana",
  "Maine",
  "Maryland",
  "Massachusetts",
  "Michigan",
  "Minnesota",
  "Mississippi",
  "Missouri",
  "Montana",
  "Nebraska",
  "Nevada",
  "New Hampshire",
  "New Jersey",
  "New Mexico",
  "New York",
  "North Carolina",
  "North Dakota",
  "Ohio",
  "Oklahoma",
  "Oregon",
  "Pennsylvania",
  "Rhode Island",
  "South Carolina",
  "South Dakota",
  "Tennessee",
  "Texas",
  "Utah",
  "Vermont",
  "Virginia",
  "Washington",
  "West Virginia",
  "Wisconsin",
  "Wyoming"
];

$("#USstate").autocomplete({
  source: USStates,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    var stateName = ui.item.name;
    var stateCities = ui.item.cities;

    if (stateName === "Alabama") {
      $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: stateCities
      });
    } else if (stateName === "Alaska") {
      $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: stateCities
      });
    } else if (stateName === "Arizona") {
      $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: stateCities
      });
    } else {
      $("#city").val("");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <span>Enter State: </span><input id="USstate">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <span>Enter City: </span><input id="city">
</div>
```

Comment: When you are using objects in the source array, they require a `label` property, which will be used for text matching.

Comment: @76484 label to where?

Comment: Instead of `"name": "Alabama"`, `"label": "Alabama"`.

Comment: Hi @user580950 you can try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1b8fn63j/)

Comment: Thanks Swati you can post this as answer, I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the names to the state dropdown, then you can filter the states and use the resulting city for the second dropdown.

Please note you will also have to change your states variable to be all uniform objects with name and cities properties if you want to have auto complete cities for the rest of the states - at the moment you only have 3 objects and the rest are strings

```js
const states = [{
    "name": "Alabama",
    "cities": ["Birmingham", "Huntsville", "Mobile", "Montgomery"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Alaska",
    "cities": ["Anchorage", "Fairbanks", "Juneau", "Sitka"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Arizona",
    "cities": ["Chandler", "Gilbert", "Glendale", "Mesa", "Phoenix", "Scottsdale", "Tempe", "Tucson"]
  },
  "Arkansas",
  "California",
  "Colorado",
  "Delaware",
  "Florida",
  "Georgia",
  "Hawaii",
  "Idaho",
  "Illinois",
  "Indiana",
  "Kansas",
  "Kentucky",
  "Louisiana",
  "Maine",
  "Maryland",
  "Massachusetts",
  "Michigan",
  "Minnesota",
  "Mississippi",
  "Missouri",
  "Montana",
  "Nebraska",
  "Nevada",
  "New Hampshire",
  "New Jersey",
  "New Mexico",
  "New York",
  "North Carolina",
  "North Dakota",
  "Ohio",
  "Oklahoma",
  "Oregon",
  "Pennsylvania",
  "Rhode Island",
  "South Carolina",
  "South Dakota",
  "Tennessee",
  "Texas",
  "Utah",
  "Vermont",
  "Virginia",
  "Washington",
  "West Virginia",
  "Wisconsin",
  "Wyoming"
];

const $city = $('#city');
$city.autocomplete();                                               // set up city auto complete

$("#USstate").autocomplete({
  source: states.map(state => state.name || state),                // set source to state names
  select: (event, ui) => {
    const state = states.filter(s => s.name === ui.item.value);    // get selected state
    
    if (state && state.length) {                                   // check if cities exists
       $city.autocomplete('option', 'source', state[0].cities);    // change city source
    } else {
       $city.autocomplete('option', 'source', []);                 // clear auto complete source
    }
    
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <span>Enter State: </span><input id="USstate">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <span>Enter City: </span><input id="city">
</div>
```